# MonoTouch binding to Pony Debugger - PDDebugger.DefaultInstance always null

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am writing a binding for pony Debugger, which should be pretty simple right?

Pony is accessed through a class member "defaultInstance"

```
@interface PDDebugger : NSObject

+ (PDDebugger *)defaultInstance;
```

Which I have implemented like this:

```
[assembly: LinkWith ("libPonyDebugger.a", LinkTarget.Simulator, ForceLoad = true)]

    namespace PonyDebugger
{
    [BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
    interface PDDebugger
    {
        [Static] [Export ("defaultInstance")]
        PDDebugger DefaultInstance { get; }

        [Export ("enableViewHierarchyDebugging")]
        PDDebugger EnableViewHierarchyDebugging();
    }
}
```

I can compile the binding fine - but when I call "PDDebugger.DefaultInstance" I just get back null. What am I missing?

How can I even be sure that the message is being passed to the underlying ObjC object?

Thanks!

[EDIT]
I have updated my bindings to:
using System;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime;

** libPonyDebugger.linkwith.cs **

```
[assembly: LinkWith ("libPonyDebugger.a", LinkTarget.Simulator, ForceLoad = true,
                     Frameworks = "Security CFNetwork Foundation CoreGraphics UIKit CoreData", LinkerFlags = "-ObjC -licucore")]

namespace PonyDebugger
{
    [BaseType (typeof (NSObject), Name="PDDebugger")]//, DisableDefaultCtor]
    interface PDDebugger
    {
        //+ (PDDebugger *)defaultInstance;
        [Static, Export ("defaultInstance")]
        PDDebugger DefaultInstance();

        [Export ("enableViewHierarchyDebugging")]
        PDDebugger EnableViewHierarchyDebugging();
    }
}
```

** libSocketRocket.linkwith.cs **

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime;

[assembly: LinkWith ("libSocketRocket.a",  LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.Simulator,
                     Frameworks = "Security CFNetwork Foundation CoreGraphics UIKit CoreData", ForceLoad = true, LinkerFlags = "-ObjC -licucore")]
```

And it all btouches/compiles to native and runs - but PDDebugger.DefaultInstance() still returns null.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting null, it probably means that the native library isn't being linked in correctly.

Are you running on Simulator or Device? How did you compile the binding? Are you sure that the native library has support for the architecture you are testing on?

Comment: Hi jstedfast - thanks for the response.
I compiled it and the sample application for the simulator - then copied libPonyDebugger.a and libSocketRocket.a from DEveloper/XCode/DerivedData into my project directory and btouch'd the lot using `btouch -unsafe --outdir=tmp -out:PonyDebugger.dll libPonyDebugger.linkwith.cs -x libSocketRocket.linkwith.cs --link-with=libPonyDebugger.a,libPonyDebugger.a --link-with=libSocketRocket.a,libSocketRocket.a -v` I think you are right - I dont think it's loading because I out log messages in the startup of Pony but dont get them coming up in console.

Comment: Oh - and Im doing all my running inside the simulator - I dont actually need device support for this...

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test to bind PonyDebugger a while ago. The bindings were fine - but it did not work, because of *method swizzling* IIRC.

From a quick review your linkwith.cs looks incomplete. Mine was:

```
[assembly: LinkWith ("libPonyDebugger.a", LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.Simulator,
    ForceLoad = true, 
    Frameworks = "Security CFNetwork CoreData", 
    LinkerFlags = "-ObjC -licucore" )]
```

I also needed to include `libSocketRocket.a`, simpler since I added the framework and flags to pony.

```
[assembly: LinkWith ("libSocketRocket.a", LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.Simulator,
    ForceLoad = true)]
```

That should give you a **non-null** instance of `PDDebugger` - but you'll need more work to get actual result out of it. Sadly I lacked time to dig it further, but let us know when you figure out the rest :-)

Comment: Thanks Poupou - hopefully that will get me a little bit further. I had added the additional frameworks (basically everything listed in the xcode projects) - but I was getting a mono native linker error referring something in licucore, I think you have the solution there. I'll give this a try tonight and report back. All I need is the UI inspection from this project anyway. I'll post it all if I get it working.

Comment: Hi Poupou, your post got me a little further, but still getting null back. I have updated my post...